# cap error trying to deploy not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu, capistrano

```
/usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require': no such file to load -- whenever/capistrano (LoadError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
from ./config/deploy.rb:16:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from Capfile:5:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:172:in `load_from_file'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
from /var/lib/gems/1.8/gems/capistrano-2.12.0/bin/cap:4
from /usr/local/bin/cap:19:in `load'
from /usr/local/bin/cap:19
```

I tried to run cap deploy and I keep getting this please help!

Comment: Do you actually have `whenever` in your gemfile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
no such file to load -- whenever/capistrano
```

You're requiring 'whenever/capistrano' somewhere (probably your `deploy.rb`), and don't have that gem.  Don't do that, or get the gem.